# Using synchronized section in onCreate() in Service

Tags: android

What for do we need to synchronize creating syncadapter in onCreate() in service? As far as I know, there is only one instance of service in system at time. So, there is no change of parallel calls onCreate().

Code from [android developers sample](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html#CreateSyncAdapterService):

```
public class SyncService extends Service {
    // Storage for an instance of the sync adapter
    private static SyncAdapter sSyncAdapter = null;
    // Object to use as a thread-safe lock
    private static final Object sSyncAdapterLock = new Object();

        public void onCreate() {
        /*
         * Create the sync adapter as a singleton.
         * Set the sync adapter as syncable
         * Disallow parallel syncs
         */
        synchronized (sSyncAdapterLock) {
            if (sSyncAdapter == null) {
                sSyncAdapter = new SyncAdapter(getApplicationContext(), true);
            }
        }
    }
...
}
```

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926361/calling-oncreate-from-different-threads-at-the-same-time.