# calling onCreate from different threads at the same time

Tags: android, android-service

I have read Android documentation in which a piece of code is synchronized inside the onCreate method, [Sync Adapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html).
AFAIK Android only creates one instance of a Service so, can Android call onCreate from different threads at the same time? or is it possible to call a Service method before onCreate has finished (using AIDL)?

Comment: Comment for Service's onCreate: `Called by the system when the service is first created.  Do not call this method directly.`.

Comment: @Simas, I am not calling this method myself.

Comment: No, all lifecycle methods will be called in context of main application thread. It is in documentation.

Comment: Then why the synchronized block in the onCreate method of this official doc?

Comment: Synchronized keyword, aside from managing access synchronization, makes calling thread owner of object's monitor, so it (thread) can use methods like `Thread.sleep` later in code.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you linked to (regarding creating `SyncAdapter` in a thread-safe manner) makes no sense. `onCreate()` of a `Service` is only ever called on the main thread, so there is no possibility that this isn't thread-safe.

Also, you cannot call any methods using AIDL before the `onCreate()` completes, because you would first need to bind to the `Service`, and you can't bind to the `Service` until `onCreate()` completes.

Comment: This is exactly what I think.